# Send request from template html file to views.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-views, jinja2

In html file I have this code, which print out information of golfelement such as golfname, changenamefee, url_1net, url_golfagora, url_juchi. I also get the golfelement ID by  `{{golfelement.key().id()}}`. There is a button `1net`, if I click the button, it will request `myapp/affiliate`

```
{% for golfelement in displaygolf %}
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ golfelement.golfname }}</td>
              <td>{{ golfelement.changenamefee }}</td>
              <td>
                  <a href="{{golfelement.url_1net}}">1net | </a>
                  <a href="{{golfelement.url_golfagora}}">Golfagora | </a>
                  <a href="{{golfelement.url_juchi}}">Juchi</a>
                  {{golfelement.key().id()}}
                  <form method="LINK" action="{{url_for('myapp/affiliate')}}">
                      <input type="submit" value="1net">
                  </form>
              </td>

          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

I want to send `{{golfelement.key().id()}}` to a function `affiliate(request, idnum)` in views.py when I click button.

```
def affiliate(request, idnum):
    golfe = Golf.get_by_id(idnum)
    return render_to_response('myapp/affiliate.html',{'affiliate': golfe})
```

Please help me how to modify the html file to send the parameter `{{golfelement.key().id()}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ url_for('myapp.affiliate') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="idnum" value="{{ golfelement.key().id() }} />
    <input type="submit" value="1net" />
</form>
```

Then your view:

```
def affiliate(request, idnum=None):
    idnum = int(idnum or request.args.get('idnum'))
    golfe = Golf.get_by_id(idnum)
    return render_to_response('myapp/affiliate.html',{'affiliate': golfe})
```

Comment: The error is "affiliate() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)". It seems I am sending only 1 argument, which is 'request'. I nee to send {{ golfelement.key.id }} to  idnum in affiliate()

Comment: By the way, I assumed A django template in my answer, but it seems you might be using jinja. I'll convert it to your setup. Also, we need to see your urlconf to see how it matches `idnum`!

Comment: thank, you are right. I am using jinja2. There is an error here "request.GET.get". It says "AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'GET'"

Comment: That's funny... are you even using django at all then?

Comment: i am using kay framework, which is built based on django and jinja2, so I think kay framework should include django. http://code.google.com/p/kay-framework/

Comment: Ah, I've never seen that. Anyway, I looked in the documentation and edited the snippet, it might work now!

Comment: uhm...it still does not work. If I just type 'request' on debug mode, the result is '<Request 'http://localhost:8085/affiliate' [GET]>'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20552/discussion-between-jesse-the-game-and-john)

Comment: I really appreciate Jesse the Game for his help.